# python 2.7 classmethod not working as wanted to[Details inside]

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code i wrote and i want the @classmethod to change the all class grade when i set_grade i set the grade 99 as you see and when i printed the instance std_1's grade it printed me the original grade i set(100) and not the one i wanted(99) and doing:

```
student.set_grade(99)
```

gave me the the same result

```
class student:

    num_of_std = 0

    def __init__(self , first , last , grade): 
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.grade = grade


    student.num_of_std += 1

    @classmethod
    def set_grade(cls , change_grade):
        cls.grade = change_grade

    def full_name(self):     
        return '{} {}: {}'.format(self.first , self.last , self.grade)


std_1 = student('Jone' , 'Jones' , 100)

std_1.set_grade(99)
print(std_1.grade)
```

Comment: Only instances that do not have grade as an instance attribute (none of them, given that it's set in `__init__`) would return the class attribute instead.

Comment: You use a classmethod to set the class attribute `grade`, but then access the instance attribute, so of course, you get the value of the instance attribute. If you want the class attribute then you need to access it *on the class*, so `student.grade`. As an aside, you should stick to PEP8 conventions and use `UpperCase` for class names

Comment: doing     student.set_grade(99) giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

First, this code doesn't run for me as written. the `student.num_of_std += 1` gives an error, because student isn't defined at that point.

So, I've slightly modified your code as follows, hopefully preserving your intention:

```
class student:

num_of_std = 0

def __init__(self , first , last , grade): 
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.grade = grade
    student.num_of_std += 1

@classmethod
def set_grade(cls , change_grade):
    cls.grade = change_grade

def full_name(self):     
    return '{} {}: {}'.format(self.first , self.last , self.grade)


std_1 = student('Jone' , 'Jones' , 100)

std_1.set_grade(99)
print("std_1.grade: " + str(std_1.grade))
print("student.grade: " + str(student.grade))
```

I get

```
std_1.grade: 100
student.grade: 99
```

as my output.

As you can see, the class method you've defined changes the `grade` attribute on the *class* itself, ***not*** on the instance it is called with. When you access `std_1.grade`, you get the *instance* attribute, which is unchanged, hence still `100`.

If you want to change the grade for the instance you call `set_grade` with, remove the `@classmethod` annotation.

I'm not quite sure what behavior you're expecting, if this doesn't answer your question please leave me a comment and I can update my answer to explain.